# Machine learning matching methods?

Tags: machine-learning, python, record-linkage

My goal is match each of the invoices created to each payment made. So for example, if I have a set of invoices:

```
InvoiceDate InvoiceCategory
02/21/2016  Amazon 
08/17/2016  BestBuy
08/17/2016  Amazon
08/21/2016  BestBuy
```

Let's say each of those rows are matched respectively with each row here:

```
PaymentDate PaymentCategory
04/1/2016     Paypal
9/19/2016     Credit
9/22/2016     Paypal
9/29/2016     Check
```

That is, `02/21/2016  Amazon` matches with `04/1/2016     Paypal` and so on.

I want to then train some model on this training set. I want the model to figure out from the example above that the `PaymentDate` comes roughly a month after each `InvoiceDate`. And that `BestBuy` matches more closely to `Check` than `Paypal` (because intuitively, Best Buy accepts check payment but not Paypal)

So if my test set consists of

```
InvoiceDate InvoiceCategory           PaymentDate PaymentCategory
02/21/2015  Amazon                      9/19/2015     Credit
08/17/2015  BestBuy                     04/1/2015     Paypal
```

Then the ML should predict that `02/21/2015  Amazon` matches with `04/1/2015     Paypal` and `08/17/2015  BestBuy` matches with `9/19/2015     Credit`

I've heard about `recordlinkage` in Python. However, it seems to only link records with identical values. That won't work in my case because in the example above `02/21/2015` matches with `04/1/2015` even though their dates are different

But what ML model matches records like this?

Comment: Did you try some of the references from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage  or https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.no/&httpsredir=1&article=2572&context=cstech ?